# Clear state in providers when using Flutter and Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

How can I clear the current state of my Riverpod providers manually in my Flutter app? The use case I have is when a user signs out of my app then signs up as a new/different user the previous users state is still stored in the providers, it is cleared automatically when the app is restarted however.

Comment: You may want to see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69960102/clear-all-cache-data-listener-state-of-provider-using-flutter-riverpod

Answer (score 14):

### 2022

There is now an [invalidate()](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/Ref/invalidate.html) method that causes the provider to be disposed immediately.

Example usage:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
                          ref.read(newPostScreenProvider.notifier).setBusy(true);
await ref.read(newPostScreenProvider.notifier).submitPost(
          image: ref.watch(imagesProvider),
          content: ref.watch(contentProvider),
          private: private,
        );
                          
    ref.read(newPostScreenProvider.notifier).setBusy(false);
    ref.invalidate(newPostScreenProvider);
    ref.invalidate(imagesProvider);
    ref.invalidate(contentProvider);
    ref.invalidate(contentReadyProvider);
    router.pop();
}
```

Here's a [GitHub issue describing the invalidate method](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/1295).

Comment: This does not seem to work as one might desire when using `keepAlive`. Invalidating a .keepAlive` provider triggers the provider to rebuild right away.

Answer (score 7):

For reference, my question was answered by the owner of the Riverpod package here:
https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/676

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use .autoDispose from Riverpod, see below link for more details

```
final userProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<YourModel>((ref) {

});
```

https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/auto_dispose/

Comment: Hi, I’m aware of auto dispose, but my use case is different. I don’t want to use auto dispose for some of the providers while a user is logged in. But when that user logs out, I somehow need to find a way to dispose all providers, so that when I login on the same device with a different user, the state is reset. Makes sense?

Comment: @SaschaDerungs I have the exact same issue. Did you solve this? I can't seem to find a way to clear all providers on signout.

Comment: I solve the problem by setting the provider to the screen that comes after login, so when you click logout and you will remove all routes (that will dispose your provider) and navigate to the login page

Comment: Tip: If you are using `.autoDispose` then you can use an "empty" watch to keep the provider alive like this `ref.watch(myProvider.select(() {}))`. [source](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/2538#issuecomment-1541763588)

Comment: To dispose all the providers when user is logged out, you ll need to remove all the references to your providers which are not disposed because they still are referenced. This happens when corresponding widgets are in the widget tree.

Comment: I enjoy using Riverpod in most cases, but it's really annoying that simple use cases like this cannot be done. You'll need to have a proper way of doing it defined by the author, I get it, you should observe "logged in" state... so other state would be refreshed after log out. But most of the state management has a reset feature, and it's perfectly legit to use in sign out case.

Comment: The proposed solution is very error prone. What if someone forget to observe the logged in provider. Keeping states across login sessions is just a dangerous thing